# How to display log message when an activity is started in Android

Tags: android, android-widget

I am in one activity say Activity A. I am calling another activity B.
In activity A I write the following Statement:
 startActivity(new Intent(this,ActivityB.class));

Now, I want to log a  debug message  only when Activity A is able to successfully launch ActivityB.
How can I achieve this feature in Android.
Any kind of Help is appreciated
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) method to achieve this. Use this in your Activity "A"

Or else if thats not what you are looking for, I am guessing you want to log when activity B starts and stos. Activity class provides [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) methods for start, stop, pause resume, etc.
Override them and put your logging code in there:

```
  public class B extends Activity {

      private static final String TAG = "B-Activity";

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Activity created"); // or Log.d for debug
      }

      @Override
      public void onStart() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Activity started"); // or Log.d for debug
      }

  }
```